# Derby Database error not writing to database

Tags: sql, database, derby

Not sure why but recently a machine running derby database for 3 years or so has stopped working its running a software we wrote and using derby database. The software imports images and writes the location into derby database. There is enough space on the derby database it seems but not sure if database has gone corrupt or why it won't write to it anymore. Here is some of the error logs:

```
 9-Apr-2019 19:29:43,575  ERROR 574f7773-98c0-43cd-9550-f41eb34951ab-SIMP StorageResourceDefaultImpl:190 - Error rollbacking transaction for the file: ..\image_storage\image_374\SL000ED88_1556785502569.bif
org.apache.commons.transaction.file.ResourceManagerSystemException: 16a36a59978-2962: Database is set to dirty, this *may* mean it is corrupt. No modifications are allowed until a recovery run has been performed! (ERR_SYSTEM)
at org.apache.commons.transaction.file.FileResourceManager.txInitialSaneCheckForWriting(FileResourceManager.java:996)
at org.apache.commons.transaction.file.FileResourceManager.rollbackTransaction(FileResourceManager.java:615)
at com.bioimagene.iii.ims.service.storage.impl.StorageResourceDefaultImpl.rollback(StorageResourceDefaultImpl.java:187)
at com.bioimagene.iii.ims.service.storage.impl.StorageResourceDefaultImpl.<init>(StorageResourceDefaultImpl.java:103)
at com.bioimagene.iii.ims.service.storage.impl.StorageServiceDefaultImpl.createStorageResource(StorageServiceDefaultImpl.java:59)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor183.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
at $Proxy64.createStorageResource(Unknown Source)
at com.bioimagene.iii.ims.server.impl.SaveImageRequestProcessorDelegateBase.processSaveImage(SaveImageRequestProcessorDelegateBase.java:115)
at com.bioimagene.iii.ims.server.impl.SaveImageRequestProcessorDelegateBase.processSaveImageRequest(SaveImageRequestProcessorDelegateBase.java:87)
at com.bioimagene.iii.ims.server.impl.SaveLocalImageRequestProcessorDelegate.processSaveLocalImageRequest(SaveLocalImageRequestProcessorDelegate.java:37)
at com.bioimagene.iii.ims.server.impl.ImsServerJbossRemotingImpl.processSaveLocalImageRequest(ImsServerJbossRemotingImpl.java:622)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
at $Proxy69.processSaveLocalImageRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.bioimagene.iii.ims.command.impl.SaveLocalImageRequestHandlerCommand.execute(SaveLocalImageRequestHandlerCommand.java:26)
at com.bioimagene.iii.ims.server.impl.DefaultImsClientRequestHandlerImpl.invoke(DefaultImsClientRequestHandlerImpl.java:89)
at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:908)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:742)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:695)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:522)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:230)
19-Apr-2019 19:29:43,591  ERROR 574f7773-98c0-43cd-9550-f41eb34951ab-SIMP StorageResourceDefaultImpl:121 - Error starting storage transaction [id: 16a36a59978-2962] for the folder: image_storage\image_374
com.bioimagene.iii.ims.commons.exception.ImsStorageRollbackException: Error rollbacking transaction for the file:
```

Does anyone know how to fix this and stop getting this errors? thx

Comment: Is there a derby.log? Does it have any more info?

Comment: @BryanPendleton I know which derby.log you are talking about but I don't seem to know its exact location as the application i am running has derby embedded in it. I can try to look around though and let you know.

Comment: @BryanPendleton got this error
Mon Apr 15 23:00:37 CEST 2019 Thread[DRDAConnThread_901,5,derby.daemons] Cleanup action starting
java.sql.SQLException: Database 'DB2' not found.
 at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)

Comment: In the exception detail that you included above, **none** of those messages are from Derby. Derby messages would be from org.apache.derby.* classes. I think you need to get some help from Apache Commons experts who know about org.apache.commons.transaction.* classes.

Answer (score 0):

The log error you provided:

```
... Database is set to dirty, this *may* mean it is corrupt. No modifications are allowed until a recovery run has been performed! (ERR_SYSTEM)
```

suggests that the database is in an inconsistent state (eg. the database was not cleanly shutdown, or there was a system crash, or corruption due to operating system disk-sync or IO problems, sudden power outage, unscheduled automatic forced Windows Update reboot etc).

Try performing a Crash Recovery by performing a controlled startup, shutdown and restart of the affected (or all) databases (ie. reboot):

If you are running in Client-Server mode, then:

```
ij> /* Startup */
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample';
ij> 
ij> /* Shutdown */
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/;shutdown=true';
ERROR XJ015: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 50000, SQLSTATE: XJ015, SQLERRMC: Derby system shutdown.
ij> quit;

PS C:\db-derby-10.13.1.1-bin\bin> ### Shutdown Network Server ###
PS C:\db-derby-10.13.1.1-bin\bin> .\NetworkServerControl shutdown
Mon Apr 22 03:14:46 AEST 2019 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.13.1.1 - (1765088) shutdown
PS C:\db-derby-10.13.1.1-bin\bin>
```

(If you are running in Embedded mode, then you would need to execute an `ij` shutdown connect string for each database (eg. `connect 'jdbc:derby:c:\derby\databases\sample;shutdown=true';`). Refer to the "Database connection examples" section in the "Derby Developer's Guide" for information on all the styles of connect strings for Embedded mode).

Then start up Derby and/or your application.

(By performing a controlled startup (ie. startup, shutdown and restart), on the restart step Derby tries to detect any database inconsistencies that may have occurred (due to something like a system crash). It will try to use the Active Logs to rollforward (or rollback) any bad transactions to the last known good commit. This is one of the first lines of defense against data corruption. However Crash Recovery has limits, for example if your database files are so broken or the parts of it that are inconsistent is too old beyond what is kept in the Active Logs, then you may need to restore the database from a good backup. Refer to the "Derby Developer's Guide" for further details on how recovery works):

> **Booting databases**
>
> The default configuration for Derby is to boot (or
>   start) a database when an application first makes a connection to it.
>   When Derby boots a database, it checks to see if recovery needs to be
>   run on the database, so in some unusual cases booting can take some
>   time. You can also configure your system to automatically boot all
>   databases in the system when it starts up; see "derby.system.bootAll"
>   in the Derby Reference Manual.
>
> ...
>
> **Storage and recovery**
>
> If the system or operating system fails unexpectedly, when Derby next
>   starts up it can use the log to perform recovery, recovering the
>   "lost" transactions from the log and rolling back uncommitted
>   transactions. Recovery ensures that all committed transactions at the
>   time the system failed are applied to the database, and all
>   transactions that were active are rolled back. Thus the databases are
>   left in a consistent, valid state.

Then try checking table consistency:

```
ij>
SELECT schemaname, tablename,
SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CHECK_TABLE(schemaname, tablename)
FROM sys.sysschemas s, sys.systables t
WHERE s.schemaid = t.schemaid;
...
...
...
SYS
   |SYSVIEWS
       |1

31 rows selected
ij>
```

In the worst case, you may need to restore from backup.

If you have turned on Online Log Archiving, then you can perform a Roll-forward Recovery.

(See the "Maintaining database integrity" section of the "Derby Administration Guide" for more information on the SYSCS_CHECK_TABLE function, backups and restores and log archiving, and Roll-forward recovery).

Comment: so after I shut it down then execute this to start it?

ij> /* Startup */
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample';

Comment: @JCLopez - Yes. Attempt to shut it down cleanly by starting ij, and type `connect 'jdbc:derby://<server>:<port>/<database>;shutdown=true';`. It might be a good idea to first stop your application (so that you can isolate the database and use ij on it while it is not processing anything). Startup: `connect 'jdbc:derby://<server>:<port>/<database>';`.If your application stops the Derby network server, then the connect string is slightly different - try using the Embedded mode URL (ie. `connect 'jdbc:derby:<fullpath_to_database_directory>;shutdown=true';`).Then similarly try starting it up again.

Comment: the application I believe does stop the derby database as I have tried connecting to it and it won't connect if application is stopped. But will try to connect to it while application is off hope it can connect.

Comment: @JCLopez - You do not need your application to be running in order to connect to the database. Just specify the embedded protocol in the `ij` connect string (eg. `connect 'jdbc:derby:c:\myapp\mydatabase';`). This requires that you know the location of where the database is stored on disk (search the "derby.log" for "Booting Derby version ... on database directory" to find it).

Comment: got this error on derby.log 
    Mon Apr 15 23:00:37 CEST 2019 
    Thread[DRDAConnThread_901,5,derby.daemons] Cleanup action starting
    java.sql.SQLException: Database 'DB2' not found.
 at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)

Comment: and don't think we have a DB2 database just DB

Comment: @JCLopez -  "DB2" in that error message does not mean Derby is trying to connect to an IBM DB2 database. It could mean that the path you specified in the connect string is either incorrect, or not readable and/or writable by Derby. For example, if your connect string is `jdbc:derby:c:\myapp\mydirectory\db2`, then make sure that the whole path exists and try recursively granting full permissions and ownership to the db2 folder and all of its subfolders and files.

Comment: @JCLopez  - FYI a "database name" in Derby is the directory name where your database files are stored (for that specific database).

Comment: the directory we have is called DB this is on windows. It is trying to find a folder per se. Not sure why someone in my team named DB but i think that might be confusing. Let's call it TESTDB for example, i do see a folder with this name but not TESTDB2 for example. So the path is incorrect somewhere but trying to find out where this was specified.

Comment: @JCLopez - Maybe because it rhymes with "derby" ... Anyway, if TESTDB has a "log" and "seg0" subdirectory, then it is likely a Derby database. TESTDB2 might be specified in an application properties file, or even hardcoded in the source. Maybe TESTDB2 got recently moved or deleted ? (suggest checking your organisation's Change Control records) -- If assuming that these two databases are the same, then try copying TESTDB to TESTDB2 and see what happens.